What causes this ugly blending between certain colors, and how do I fix it?
I'm working on a game and while using some debug colors with high contrast, I noticed that the edges blend together in a way that I find unattractive :


At first I thought it was the shader I wrote to do a custom downscaling. But After simply blurring it in my photo editing program, I saw that the problem persisted there as well :

From the blue side, the brightness seems to increase as you approach the edge. From the red, it appears to get darker, before rapidly changing into an intermediate color. The overall effect makes the edge more dramatic and jarring.
I also tried blurring blue and yellow together. You see another dramatic effect - the colors blend into an extremely bright white color and at the core is a hard edge :

Curious how I can resolve this.
Also, are there any resources where I can learn more about this effect? I searched around but had no idea what search terms to use.

Have you tried converting to a perceptual colour space before blending, then converting the result back to RGB for display?

No, but I will. Was thinking it was maybe something to do with the gamma being wrong when blended in rgb.

What you are describing sounds like an optical illusion (as DMGregory hinted, related to the way that human eyes perceive color). It could also be affected by your monitor's color calibration. My monitor is calibrated with a colorimeter and I don't notice the issue with brightness that you describe.
